# Android Intent Share not working properly

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new to android app development.
Here is the scenario.
1. **Main Activity**
2. **Second Activity**
3. **RecyclerView Adapter** connected to **Second Activity**

I'm navigating from Main Activity to Second Activity that contains a list of cards.

Each card has a share button.

When I'm clicking on share button instead of opening Intent Chooser it is navigating to Main Activity(not back to Main Activity but a fresh reload)

Here's my code in onBindViewHolder method

```
holder.share.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() 
{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Random Text");
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send To"));
            }
});
```

context is passed from Second Activity.

**Question 1:**
*Is there anything wrong with the structure of the code?*
**Question 2:**
*Should I not put this code in onBindViewHolder method?*
**Question 3:**
*Is there any different way to implement Sharing Intent in RecyclerView Adapter?*

Here is my Adapter Code:

```
    public class FavQuoteRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavQuoteRecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    {
        private List<Quote> list;
        private Context ctx;
        private SharedPreferences sp;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        private String jsonList;
        private Layout_to_Image layout_to_image;
        private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
        private Bitmap bitmap;

    public FavQuoteRecyclerView(List<Quote> list, Context context)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.ctx = context;
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.shared_preference_name, 0);
        editor = sp.edit();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FavQuoteRecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.row_quote, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FavQuoteRecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Quote quote = list.get(position);
        holder.favQuote.setText(quote.getQuote());
        holder.favAuthor.setText(quote.getAuthor());
        holder.favCat.setText(quote.getCat());
        holder.favFavButton.setLiked(true);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(quote.getUrl()).noPlaceholder().into(holder.favBGPic);
        holder.favShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                constraintLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.fav_main_constraint_layout_id);
                layout_to_image = new Layout_to_Image(ctx, constraintLayout);
                bitmap = layout_to_image.convert_layout();

                String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ctx.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", "share it maximum");
                Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"bitmapUri");
                ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Title"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView favQuote;
        public TextView favAuthor;
        public TextView favCat;
        public LikeButton favFavButton;
        public ImageView favBGPic;
        public ImageView favShareButton;

        public ViewHolder(final View view)
        {
            super(view);
            favQuote = view.findViewById(R.id.fav_quote_id);
            favAuthor = view.findViewById(R.id.fav_author_id);
            favCat = view.findViewById(R.id.fav_cat_id);
            favFavButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fav_remove_fav_button);
            favBGPic = view.findViewById(R.id.fav_bg_pic);
            favShareButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fav_share_button);

            favFavButton.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
                @Override
                public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                }

                @Override
                public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                    list.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    jsonList = new Gson().toJson(list);
                    editor.putString(Constants.list_of_fav_quote, jsonList);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vipercorporation.myquotes">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity android:name=".FavQuoteActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: didi you set any other click event on any other component ?

Comment: Yes, There is one like button. But it is not using anything related to Intent.

Comment: can you post your manifest file and whole adapter class

Comment: This can mean your app get crashed . Make sure `context` is not null . Also check `LogCat`.

Comment: Show your adapter's code

Comment: Piggybacking on what @ADM said, try putting a breakpoint inside your onClick method to see if that block is getting reached. If your context isn't null you might be getting a ActivityNotFoundException where your device can't handle the intent you're trying to start. In this case, use the PackageManager to see if your intent can be handled.

Comment: post full code for RecylcerView's Adapter and also check in your Logcat is there kind of crash?

Comment: `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(....));`

Comment: @Ankita I have added Adapter code

Comment: @Vishal Malviya Put   constraintLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.fav_main_constraint_layout_id); ouside the onclick() block.

Comment: @Ankita could you please tell me why? It'd be great.

Comment: Have you tried this? Try it once if it will work then I will explain . @VishalMalaviya

Comment: @Ankita Okay let me try

Comment: Visal, why do you need to implement click listener(s) at Adapter code? And, I don't think any solution will be stable for you. Use interfaces: put the code in your activity

Comment: @Toaster I want start a sharing Intent for each card present in RecyclerView

Comment: @Ankita I moved constraint layout handler in ViewHolder but still It didn't work

Comment: @VishalMalaviya that can also be done, when cards are added dynamically

Comment: @Toaster You mean in a ViewHolder class?

Comment: Can we talk further in chat ? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174518/in-reply-to-stackoverflow-question-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-51184014

Comment: @Toaster sorry it's read only for me

Comment: @VishalMalaviya Sorry, you don't have 20 reputation, it's mandatory here